# Combine multiple result sets into a single table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

**Scenario:** I need to prepare a documentation of excel sheet for a permission matrix. Totally 15 roles and 20 modules in the application, using an user-defined function to passing the roleid and moduleid, I get the individual role's permission details and I can copy and paste into excel sheet.

But going forward, I'm repeating the same task for 300 times. To reduce the work, I'm planning to combine all the role's permission in module wise. So I can do the task only 20 times.

**What I have tried**: I have created an UDF function to split the comma separated results from the SP into column wise. Also creating 20 variables to store the each role's permission details in the table format.

**Sample Data and Tables**: Consider each `@UDF_Function` stored the each role's permission details and I want to display all the results in a single table format.

```
DECLARE @UDF_Function1 TABLE (Details VARCHAR (10));
INSERT INTO @UDF_Function1 (Details) 
SELECT 'hidden' UNION ALL SELECT 'edit' UNION ALL SELECT 'edit';

DECLARE @UDF_Function2 TABLE (Details VARCHAR (10));
INSERT INTO @UDF_Function2 (Details) 
SELECT 'view' UNION ALL SELECT 'edit' UNION ALL SELECT 'view';

-- SELECT * FROM @UDF_Function1;
-- SELECT * FROM @UDF_Function2;

SELECT F1.Details AS R1, F2.Details AS R2 FROM 
(SELECT * FROM @UDF_Function1) F1,
(SELECT * FROM @UDF_Function2) F2;
```

The output result is not in my expected format, How can I achieve in the expected format as below?

**Expected Result**:

```
| R1        | R2      |
|---------------------|
| hidden    | view    |
| edit      | edit    |
| edit      | view    |
```

Mine is SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @UDF_Function1 TABLE (id int identity,Details VARCHAR (10));
INSERT INTO @UDF_Function1 (Details) 
SELECT 'hidden' UNION ALL SELECT 'edit' UNION ALL SELECT 'edit';

DECLARE @UDF_Function2 TABLE (id int identity,Details VARCHAR (10));
INSERT INTO @UDF_Function2 (Details) 
SELECT 'view' UNION ALL SELECT 'edit' UNION ALL SELECT 'view';


SELECT F1.Details AS R1, F2.Details AS R2 FROM 
(SELECT * FROM @UDF_Function1) F1,
(SELECT * FROM @UDF_Function2) F2 WHERE F1.id=F2.id;
```

In your query you need join condition supplied in `WHERE` clause for which i have used self generating identity column `id`.
Without join condition Cartesian product between rows of the two tables is occurring giving more than required result number of rows.

Comment: Returns my expected result, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add identity column and do a simple join

```
DECLARE @UDF_Function1 TABLE (id int identity,Details VARCHAR (10));
INSERT INTO @UDF_Function1 (Details) 
SELECT 'hidden' UNION ALL SELECT 'edit' UNION ALL SELECT 'edit';

DECLARE @UDF_Function2 TABLE (id int identity,Details VARCHAR (10));
INSERT INTO @UDF_Function2 (Details) 
SELECT 'view' UNION ALL SELECT 'edit' UNION ALL SELECT 'view';


SELECT F1.Details AS R1, F2.Details AS R2 
FROM @UDF_Function1 f1 inner join @UDF_Function2 f2 on f1.id=f2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use cte yoo, like this:

```
with 
UDF_Function1 (id, Details) as (
select 1,  'hidden'
union all 
select 2,  'edit'
union all 
select 3,  'edit'
),
 UDF_Function2 (id, Details) as (
select 1,  'view'
union all 
select 2,  'edit'
union all 
select 3,  'view'
)

SELECT F1.Details AS R1, F2.Details AS R2 
FROM UDF_Function1 f1 inner join UDF_Function2 f2 on f1.id=f2.id
```